# Build a Windows Desktop Application from a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, desktop-application

I have build a fairly decent sized Ruby on Rails Application that works just fine. It exposes data via Rest API calls to the users, that is authenticated via token based authentication and Devise.

But now a few clients are wanting to have the application on-premise. They want their developers(windows developers) to work on the data, but in offline mode.

I have no idea if a Ruby on Rails App can be converted to a Windows Desktop App. Or do I have to build the desktop App from scratch? The Desktop App will NOT have a GUI, as the client just needs the data in Json format(Just like API calls during web-app).

The Desktop App will also have a license information too that needs to be stored in an encrypted way.

I am a complete newbee to desktop apps so please pardon me if this question seems really stupid.

Comment: Please comment here the reason for your negative votes, if any

Comment: I didn't do the downvote but probably because you are asking a pretty general question and SO is best for specific issues that can be contained in, say, a code snippet. At any rate, you could probably run an on premises copy of your app and then release the frontend rolled up in an Electron desktop app that had its API calls directed at the on-premises server. Here's the product's site: https://electron.atom.io/

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's a project to do what you want to do. http://enclose.io will allow you to package your app for windows clients.

Comment: Thats a great find. But I couldn't figure out how to make the downloaded rubyc work? I am on linux, and "which rubyc" doesn't produce anything.
Have you tried it out?

Comment: No, i have not tried :(